# Create and Plot the PDF and CDF of the Continuous Uniform Distribution using Sympy

Tags: python, matplotlib, sympy, holoviews, cdf

Using Sympy:

How can I define the PDF and CDF of the Continuous Uniform Distribution and also generate a plot for the pdf as well as the cdf?

Answer (score 0):

1. Here's a good way of doing this:

   ```
    # import libaries
    import sympy as sp
    from sympy.stats import Uniform, density, cdf

    # define necessary symbols
    a, b, x = sp.symbols('a b x')

    # define the pdf of the cont uniform distribution
    f = 1 / (b - a)
    cont_uniform_pdf = sp.Piecewise((f, ((b >= x) & (a <= x))), (0, True))

    # define the cdf of the cont uniform distribution
    F = (x - a) / (b - a)
    cont_uniform_cdf = sp.Piecewise((0, a > x), (F, x<b), (1, True))

    # choose the a and b parameter of the distribution
    a_value = 1
    b_value = 5

    # use .subs() to fill in the chosen parameters in the pdf and cdf
    pdf_plot = sp.plot(
        cont_uniform_pdf.subs({'a': a_value, 'b': b_value}), 
        title=f'pdf of $U \sim ({a_value}, {b_value})$', 
        xlim=(0, 6), size=(5., 2.), show=False,)

    cdf_plot = sp.plot(
        cont_uniform_cdf.subs({'a': a_value, 'b': b_value}), 
        title=f'cdf of $U \sim ({a_value}, {b_value})$', 
        xlim=(0, 6), size=(5., 2.), show=False,)

    # use a plotgrid to display both plots below eachother
    plot_grid = sp.plotting.PlotGrid(2, 1, pdf_plot, cdf_plot, show=False)
    plot_grid.show()
   ```

   [image: sympy plot continuous uniform distribution]

2. Alternatively you can create the continuous distribution using the stats part from sympy. This results in the same plot:

   ```
    # create the uniform distribution
    X = Uniform('x', a, b)

    # use density() to create the pdf and subs to fill in the chosen parameter values for a and b
    pdf_plot = sp.plot(
        (density(X)(x)).subs({'a': a_value, 'b': b_value}),
        title=f'pdf of $U \sim ({a_value}, {b_value})$', 
        xlim=(0, 6), size=(5., 2.), show=False,)

    # use cdf() to create the pdf and subs to fill in the chosen parameter values for a and b
    cdf_plot = sp.plot(
        (cdf(X)(x)).subs({'a': a_value, 'b': b_value}), 
        title=f'cdf of $U \sim ({a_value}, {b_value})$', 
        ylabel='F(x)',
        xlim=(0, 6), size=(5., 2.), show=False,)

    # use a plotgrid to display both plots below eachother
    plot_grid = sp.plotting.PlotGrid(2, 1, pdf_plot, cdf_plot, show=False)
    plot_grid.show()
   ```

3. Finally you could also decide to use your own preferred plotting library. In this case, convert the sympy class or function to a regular python function with `sp.lambdify()` :

   ```py
   import holoviews as hv
   hv.extension('bokeh')

   # use sp.lambdify() to convert your sympy function to a regular python function
   fx = sp.lambdify(x, cont_uniform_pdf.subs({a: a_value, b: b_value}))
   Fx = sp.lambdify(x, cont_uniform_cdf.subs({a: a_value, b: b_value}))

   x_values = np.linspace(0, 6, num=1000)

   # create plots in this case using holoviews as the plotting library
   pdf_plot = hv.Curve(zip(x_values, fx(x_values)), label='cont uniform PDF')
   cdf_plot = hv.Curve(zip(x_values, Fx(x_values)), label='cont uniform CDF')

   pdf_plot + cdf_plot
   ```

[image: plotting continuous uniform using holoviews]